# React-native-video without npm eject

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, create-react-native-app

I'm fairly new to React Native development, and I'm trying to include a video player in my mobile app. I created the application with `create-react-native-app` and have been viewing it in Expo by running `npm start`.

However, when I try to use packages like `react-native-video`, `react-native-video-controls`, and `react-native-video-player`, I get the following warning: "Warning: Native component for "RCTVideo" does not exist." Example usage:

```
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-controls';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <VideoPlayer source={{uri: './media_files/Intro'}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I look up RCTVideo, I find solutions saying I should add `RCTVideo.xcodeproj` to my XCode project. As far as I know, this suggests that I should have ejected the application *before* trying to run video. Is this correct? And is there any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

try this use `require` insteaad of `uri`

```
<Video
     ...
    source={require('./media_files/Intro')}
    ...
  />
```

I have never had `uri` work on any component I have ever used.

Comment: This gives me the same "Warning: Native component for "RCTVideo" does not exist" error.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: No worries - after ejecting, both the `require` and `uri` methods seem to work as expected.